# How to merge a trained model and an untrained one?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I'm having a hard time on doing the following:

- I have a model with 125,089,410 trainable params which I've already trained;
- The model outputs two tensors with shape (None, 96);
- I wanted to build a new model by freezing the layers from the previous model and then output a single (None, 96) tensor.

Important: I have no intention of adding more layers into the original model I've trained.

Here's what I've been trying:

```py
def get_output_model (prev_model):

    # Freezing prev model
    for l in prev_model.layers:
        l.trainable = False

    # Compiling so it won't complain about parameters number
    prev_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy')

    # Sanity check
    print (prev_model.summary())

    # Loss function
    def loss_fn(y_true, y_pred):
        pass # This doesn't matter here

    # Building model
    out_model_in = prev_model.output
    out_model = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2 * MAX_LEN, activation='linear')(out_model_in)
    out_model = tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu')(out_model)
    out_model = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(out_model)
    out_model = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2 * MAX_LEN, activation='linear')(out_model)
    out_model = tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu')(out_model)
    out_model = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(out_model)
    out_model = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2 * MAX_LEN, activation='linear')(out_model)
    out_model = tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu')(out_model)
    out_model = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(out_model)
    out_model = tf.keras.layers.Dense(MAX_LEN, activation='linear')(out_model)
    out_model = tf.keras.layers.Activation('softmax')(out_model)
    model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[out_model_in], outputs=[out_model])
    model.compile(loss=loss_fn, optimizer='nadam', metrics=['accuracy', f1_m])
```

but then it gives me:

```
ValueError: Layer dense_49 expects 1 inputs, but it received 2 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'activation_57/Identity:0' shape=(None, 96) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'activation_58/Identity:0' shape=(None, 96) dtype=float32>]
```

I understand this error is expected but I have no idea how to workaround this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a way of doing that and it works for me:

```py
def get_output_model (prev_model):

    # Freezing prev model
    for l in prev_model.layers:
        l.trainable = False

    # Compiling so it won't complain about parameters number
    prev_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy')

    # Sanity check
    print (prev_model.summary())

    # Loss function
    def loss_fn(y_true, y_pred):
        pass # This doesn't matter here

    # Building model
    x1 = prev_model.output[0]
    x2 = prev_model.output[1]
    out_model = tf.keras.layers.Add()([x1, x2])
    out_model = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2 * MAX_LEN, activation='linear')(out_model)
    out_model = tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu')(out_model)
    out_model = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(out_model)
    out_model = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2 * MAX_LEN, activation='linear')(out_model)
    out_model = tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu')(out_model)
    out_model = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(out_model)
    out_model = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2 * MAX_LEN, activation='linear')(out_model)
    out_model = tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu')(out_model)
    out_model = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(out_model)
    out_model = tf.keras.layers.Dense(MAX_LEN, activation='linear')(out_model)
    out_model = tf.keras.layers.Activation('softmax')(out_model)
    model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[prev_model.input], outputs=[out_model])
    model.compile(loss=loss_fn, optimizer='nadam', metrics=['accuracy', f1_m])
    return model
```